# How is this complex generic Makefile rule constructed

Tags: gcc, makefile, gcov

Several modules each are tested independently with their own test_$(MODULE).c.
A shared library has been generated $(LIBRARY) containing modules without coverage.  $(basename $<).o should override the one in $(LIBRARY).  For some reason, I get results as if they are not overridden.  Can someone review this and make suggestions on fixes?  Currently I have non-generic gcov rules for each of the five objects.  These gcovs work correctly.  Below I show the generic rule and one specific use of the rule.

```
SHARED_OPTS=-O0 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC
GOPTS=$(SHARED_OPTS) -g -coverage -pg

%.gcov : %
    @echo "\t$@ generic (needs work)"
    @-gcc $(GOPTS) -c -o test_$(basename $<).o test_$<
    @-gcc $(GOPTS) -c -o      $(basename $<).o      $<
    @-gcc $(GOPTS)    -o gcov_test_$(basename $<) \
        test_$(basename $<).o \
        $(basename $<).o \
        -L . -l $(LIBRARY)
    @-./gcov_test_$(basename $<)
    @-gcov $< >$@.out 2>&1
    @echo "no Mac gprof: -gprof gcov_test_$(basename $<) gmon.out > $<.prof"
    @$(call timestamp,$@)

Unicode.c.gcov: Unicode.c
```

If anyone is interested in collaborating on high efficiency high quality Unicode lexing/parsing support by developing a shared library, I would love to have reviewers or contributors.

The Makefile fragment shown above is in a github repository:

https://github.com/jlettvin/Unicode Specifically down the c subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

While you're trying to find problems in your makefile you should avoid using `@`, as it hides the command line and so you can't see issues.  Also you should avoid `-` here: if any of those commands fail you certainly don't want to continue to run the rest of the recipe, I wouldn't expect.

I don't know if it's a cut/paste problem but I have to assume that these lines, at least, are wrong:

```
@-gcc $(GOPTS) -c -o test_$(basename $<).o test_$<
@-gcc $(GOPTS) -c -o      $(basename $<).o      $<
```

As far as I can tell from your makefile, the last words on these lines should be `test_$<.c` and `$<.c` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  The value of $< for those two lines ends with ".c".  Remember that these lines work in specific rules, just not the generic rule.  I have so very few errors reported by construction of any object, and the interdependency of modules is so rare at this point, that using '-' means I get to see all the errors (usually none) for all objects during every compile.  Nevertheless, I will follow your advice for now.  The actual problem I am trying to solve lies elsewhere.  The naming enables .o files instrumented for gcov to be coresident with optimized .o library files.